# Testing with LIBSVM

Tags: matlab, classification, regression, svm, libsvm

I have been using libsvm in Matlab for our research. The accuracies of the model when used in cross-validation results are already quite good. However, I am having a small problem when trying to use the (already-trained) model for prediction. The svmpredict command requires us to specify the correct testing label (to be used for measuring accuracy) however I want deploy the model to classify new data (with unknown label), so of course there is no label for this testing data. Can I call svmpredict without specifying the (target) label of the testing data? How do I deploy the models that I have obtained in a production setting?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about matlab, but in python you have the same situation. It really doesn't matter and you can predict with that value, just ignore the accuracy value on the output.